# Can I make a hole in a touch screen without ruining it?

Tags: capacitive

I need to make a big capacitive touch screen with holes inside it, can this be done without ruining the whole screen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @jsotola I need to add mechanical clickers on top of some places in the screen, one whole screen.

Comment: you could put the clickers on a sheet of plexiglass ..... use very thin wires for connections

Comment: I think this may work! I will try it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No. The pixels of the screens need to be addressed in some way – and in modern screens, that is done using a *matrix* of wires, which are very thin and arranged rectangularly.

since you can't route a wire through a hole, you couldn't even produce a concave screen shape.

Drilling a hole into any existing screen will ruin it, anyway.

Comment: You could divide a non-convex screen up into an array of convex screens, though. Or just have a non-rectangular pixel matrix. But that would mean engineering the screen from scratch, which is _far_ beyond the reach of the average hobbyist.